# Typecasting boolean

Tags: java, casting, boolean

Why can't boolean be typecast to int or byte and vice versa. For example: intuitively it seems that `(int)true` should be 1. But it gives an exception. Instead there are cases where we 'typecast'(not in true sense of the term) String to boolean like `boolean b=Boolean.valueOf("HI");`
Peace.
Faustus

Comment: Because Java is not C. It is a bit stronger typed to make it harder for folks to shoot themselves in the foot. C on the other hand gives you the gun and does you the favor of pointing it directly at your foot for you. It's very accommodating that way.

Comment: *intuitively it seems that (int)true should be 1* => how about 2? -1? This might seem intuitive when coming from a C background but it is not when you think about it.

Comment: because int has size of 4 bytes boolean has size of bit

Comment: and `Boolean.valueOf()` has nothing to do with data type casting, its just a utility method -**a bad one IMO**- to convert a string representing the word `"true"` to the boolean `true` and other words to `false`.

Comment: Don't understand downvotes for this question

Comment: @PradeepSimha - they are the same as the reason the question was closed ...

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I don't think this is a very bad question either :)

Comment: I would have thought that true should be `~0` or `-1`